# Oracle 12g XmlType store as Binary XML (select issue)

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle-xml-db, binary-xml

I am trying to select XML from DB Oracle12g. XML is stored in the table (XMLType store as binary XML) and I am not able to create Select query with where-condition. My problem is that query doesn't return any record. I am using Oracle SQL Developer 4.1.0.19.

**Examples of my queries**

```
SELECT OBJECT_VALUE
  FROM A_STUDENT_BIN
 WHERE existsNode(object_value,'//Student[@RodneCislo="123"]') = 1;

SELECT OBJECT_VALUE
  FROM A_STUDENT_BIN
 WHERE extract(OBJECT_VALUE, '//Student[@RodneCislo="123"]') IS NOT NULL;
```

**Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE a_student_bin OF XMLTYPE XMLTYPE STORE AS BINARY XML;
```

**Inserted XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250" ?>
<Vystup>
  <Student RodneCislo="123">
    <Jmeno>Pepa</Jmeno>
    <Prijmeni>Omacka</Prijmeni>
    <TitulPred>Ing.</TitulPred>
    <TitulZa></TitulZa>
  </Student>
</Vystup>
```

XML was inserted into db by query:

```
insert into A_STUDENT_BIN
values (XmlType( bfilename('MYDIR','student.xml'),
                 nls_charset_id('EE8MSWIN1250')   );
```

Comment: Oracle 11g or 12c? There is no 12g. This works fine for me in 11g. Both extract and existsnode are deprecated but as far as I'm aware should still work in 12c too. Can you see the rows without the filter? Or was the insert in a different session that hasn't committed yet, perhaps?

Comment: It is 12c. But I figured out query which works. SELECT OBJECT_VALUE FROM A_STUDENT_BIN where existsNode(object_value,'/*/*/*[@RodneCislo="123"]') = 1